# Sample data for incident triage / incident assignment

Tags: training-data

I am looking for sample data for incident triage/ incident assignment to train my model.  There are reference to opensource firefox and eclipse bug dumps in the articles published in the internet.

Eg.  https://is.muni.cz/th/374278/fi_m/thesis.pdf

But I could n't find any links pertaining to that on googling.

I got hold of a dump available in kaggle website.
https://www.kaggle.com/monika11/bug-triagingbug-assignment/version/1/data

But this doesn't have resolution for each incident.  If one any has any pointers in this regard. kindly share it.

-- Subramanian S.

Comment: Is this somehow a programming question?

Comment: Looking for training data set for machine learning using python.